# Using cosine_similarity function on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

a = np.array([[3,4],[2,5],[1,2],[1,2],[4,5]])

ap = pd.DataFrame(a, index=['Sonata','Etudes','Waltzes','Nocturnes','Marches'],columns=['search_history','view_count'])
ap
```

[image]

```
b = np.array([[4,4],[3,5],[2,1],[4,7],[1,2]])
bp = pd.DataFrame(b, index=['Sonata','Etudes','Waltzes','Nocturnes','Marches'],columns=['comment + wishlist ',' signup'])
bp
```

[image]

then i cosine_similarity function ,

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(a, b),columns=['A','B'], index=['Sonata','Etudes','Waltzes','Nocturnes','Marches'])
```

this gives:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 5), indices imply (5, 2)
```

so if i change like this,

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(a, b),columns=['A','B','c','d','e'], index=['Sonata','Etudes','Waltzes','Nocturnes','Marches'])
```

[image]

This result cames out.

This is not the result I thought.
Like dataFrames a and b, i want to show results in five rows and two columns,
but we always get results in only five rows and five columns.

What should I do?

expected result was

```
           A            B   
Sonata     0.989949     0.994692    
Etudes      0.919145    0.987241    
Waltzes     0.948683    0.997054    
Nocturnes   0.948683    0.997054    
Marches    0.993884     0.990992
```

like this

Comment: What is the expected output? behind two columns?

Comment: @Guy expected output was  A B 
Sonata 0.989949 0.994692 
Etudes 0.919145 0.987241 
Waltzes 0.948683 0.997054 
Nocturnes 0.948683 0.997054 
Marches 0.993884 0.990992  like this i added on question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cosine_similarity()` will compare every value in the array to all the values in the second array, which is `5 * 5` operations and results. You want just the first two columns, so you can slice the result `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(a, b), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], index=['Sonata', 'Etudes', 'Waltzes', 'Nocturnes', 'Marches'])
print(df[['A', 'B']]) # by columns names
# or
print(df.iloc[:, 0:2]) # by columns indices
```

Output

```
                  A         B
Sonata     0.989949  0.994692
Etudes     0.919145  0.987241
Waltzes    0.948683  0.997054
Nocturnes  0.948683  0.997054
Marches    0.993884  0.990992
```

Comment: thanks for your help. if i want to compare only  one by one  , ex) =>  Output's dataFrame's [0,0] will be result of ap's[0,0] and bp's[0,0 ]'s cosine_similarity, how can i change it?

Comment: @sksmsWKd I'm not sure what you want to do, use dynamic indices? `df.iloc[i,j]`?

Comment: i'm wondering why only 0 and 1 came when i compare array that has single element like => [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,0]]     ==> result [[1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0]]...... i want to get similarity

Comment: @sksmsWKd can you post the code? I can't reproduce those results...

Comment: to be honest, i can't write code because i'm struggling with how to make recommendation system with table ap bp (on question) and using cosine_similarity function...